# COMET или таймер?

Tags: comet, php, javascript

Привет) Понадобилось сделать чат. 
И чтобы он получал новые сообщения и выводил на экран. 
Я сделал setInetrvalом. Но наткнулся на такую вещь как COMET. 
Через которую якобы сервер делает запрос клиенту.

Лично я не представляю как это, чтобы сервер обращался к клиенту. 
Как работает COMET? Я читал статьи в интернете, но мне там чтобы понять нужно тестировать анализировать, спрашиваю уже прошариных людей) 
Неужели так и есть: сервер посылает запрос браузеру и он реагирует? Никаких бесконечных циклов и таймеров? 
И что же лучше COMET или таймер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Технология Comet — позволяет отправлять произвольные сообщения клиенту (в браузер) по инициативе сервера, это и называется push notifications или по русски push уведомления.
Данная возможность достигается путём **поддержания постоянного соединения браузера с Comet сервером**. То есть для того чтобы мы могли отправить push уведомление в браузер посетителя **необходимо поддерживать постоянное соединение с комет сервером**. Для этого используется технология websocket, а в тех браузерах которые не поддерживают websocketes используется механизм long polling ajax запросов.

Answer (score 2):

> сервер посылает запрос браузеру и он реагирует?

да (websockets) или браузер инициирует этот ответ, а сервер ответит, когда ему захочется и с желаемым результатом (long polling). Википедия еще подсказывает про бесконечный айфрейм, но это довольно темное шаманство (хоть и должно просто реализовываться и работать).
Простой интервальный опрос даст лишний оверхед.

**Обновление**

> никак

не как, соединение

> Ну частый опрос - это тоже самое, что и таймер.

Я не совсем понимаю, что имеется в виду под таймером, периодический опрос со стороны клиента или периодическая проверка "новостей" сервером внутри открытого подключения.
Бесконечный айфрейм в любом случае работает примерно как long polling (сервер отдает контент по запросу тогда, когда захочет), только одним запросом и без действий со стороны клиента (не считая выполняющегося js).

**Обновление**

[[@iproger](/users/1720/iproger)](/users/1720/iproger), я говорю, узнал о нем сегодня из википедии в статье COMET. Просто документ отдается с заголовком chunked (кусками), и браузер висит, ожидая конца передачи, в то время как сервер и не думает ее заканчивать, а просто кидает туда новые теги script с обновлениями. Технология такая же древняя, как long polling, но гораздо более неудобная в реализации.

Comment: Ну частый опрос - это тоже самое, что и таймер. Бесконечный iframe тоже, только очень извращённо. Он в бесконечном цикле когда нужно отсылает странице инфу, по сути так же как и таймер проверяет. А вот long polling - думаю как раз работает именно никак таймер, а открывается соеденение, которое ждёт ответа от сервера. Всё я правильно понимаю?

Comment: А можно реальный пример с бесконечным iframe?